# SPARK number of partitions/tasks while reading a file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, task, partition

Could someone tell me the answer to this question and why/how?

Q. How many partitions shall **intially** be created with the following command on spark shell-
sc.textfile("hdfs://user/cloudera/csvfiles")

There are 100 files in directory `/user/cloudera/csvfiles` and there are `10 nodes` running Spark.
    a.  1
    b.  10
    c.  20
    d.  100

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/198144/spark-number-of-partitionstasks-while-reading-a-fi.html

Answer (score 0):

Spark creates partitions for each HDFS blocks. It supposed to 100 partitions if each file size is less than block size of your cluster.

You can verify the same by

```
sc.textfile("hdfs://user/cloudera/csvfiles").getNumPartitions
```

Comment: Could you Explain please!